# The first one is female the second the same my whole is much dreaded pray what is my name?

Tags: riddle

> My first is female
>
> the second the same
>
> my whole is much dreaded
>
> pray what is my name?

Comment: Hi Susie, welcome to Puzzling.  This would be easier to read if you broke up the lines (or included some punctuation).

Comment: For example, is it "my whole is much dreaded pray" (and maybe "prey" not "pray") or "my whole is much dreaded/ pray, what is my name?"

Answer (score 9):

My answer is

> Malady

Because

> Ma=female, Lady=female too

combined

> much dreaded

Answer (score 7):

Is this the famed

> **Hershey** bar?

The first part of this word is

> "Her", which is female.

The second is

> "She", which is also female

The whole is much dreaded

> by everyone trying to avoid sweets in their diet - that sweet chocolate goodness is hard to resist.